# How can I express the following vector in a correct way

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression

I am dealing with the regressions. Therefore I want to express the following vector in a correct way. My $35 \times 1$ column vetor contains random numbers between 0.7 and 0.9. My idea was to express the following term like this:

$\beta_j=[0.7;0.9] \ \ \forall j\in\{1,\dots,35\} $

Is that correct ?

Comment: $\beta_J\in[0.7,0.9]$ not $=$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can it express as follows:

$(x_1,x_2,....,x_{35})^T $ with $0,7 \le x_j  \le 0,9$ for $j \in \{1,2,...,35\}$.

Comment: Much better, thanks !